# How do I structure a Silverstripe envrionment for module development and testing?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have scoured multiple blog posts on silverstripe.org and they all lead to videos/tutorials on module development that no longer exist because Silverstripe redid their entire "Lessons" section, which now focuses on how to modify an entire Silverstripe site to suit your needs.

What I'm struggling to find and understand is, what is the workflow for module development? Mostly, how do I structure an instance of Silverstripe to develop and test a module? On both 4.x and 3.x?

Module repositories contain the core code and any assets needed for the module and the module alone, as well as `composer.json` which lists libraries and modules the module depends on, of course. The problem is, if I clone the repository and run `composer install`, it will install all of that, but I do not get Silverstripe's bootstrapping code that comes with the installer - thus, I cannot test my module like this.

My instinct tells me that I should develop my module code within the `mysite` (3.x) or `app` (4.x) folder of a running Silverstripe instance (i.e. `composer create-project silverstripe/silverstripe-installer ./project-dir`), but then I'm concerned about dependency tracking - in that line of thought, modules and libs I need for development end up tracked in `./project-dir/composer.json` and not in `./project-dir/<mysite or app>/composer.json`. Manually copying my dependencies to and from each `composer.json` just seems error-prone and counter-intuitive. And if I try running `composer install` inside of `app` or `mysite`, then I end up with a `vendor` directory inside of that folder, which is unused because there's already a `vendor` directory being used by the site one level up.

Answer (score 1):

In lieu of there being some kind of "module creator wizard" available, there is inevitably going to be some manual work involved.

What I would usually do (for SilverStripe 4) is to create a folder `mymodule` in the root project and start developing in it.

The next step would be to create a repository and define a composer.json file with some basic requirements in it (like silverstripe/framework). Then you can commit and push that, and pull it into a SilverStripe 4 project with Composer (either via VCS repository configuration or via Packagist).

From here you at least have a place where your code lives. If you've set up your new module as `"type": "silverstripe-vendormodule"` then it'll be installed into `vendor/yourname/yourmodule`. You can modify the code here as needed.

You can also define the type as `"type": "silverstripe-module"` and it'll be installed into the project root. Most modules are going down the vendor road in SilverStripe 4 though, so it's advisable to follow suit.

In SilverStripe 3 you could do the same thing as this, but because the Composer installer for SilverStripe 3 modules puts them into the project root by default you can create arbitrary folder names like `mymodule` in your root project and immediately start developing in them.

The SilverStripe manifests will read any folder that doesn't have a `_manifest-exclude` file in it, and has either a `_config.php` file or `_config` folder in it, so it's easy to get going and you can always convert this folder into a module of its own at any point, delete it then include it again with Composer requirements. You can do this in SilverStripe 4 as well.